# how to set read only properties to the  particular info path form control based on user logged in?

Tags: infopath, form

how to set read only properties to the  particular info path form control based on user logged in?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you select the field and go to the "Fields" pane, you can add a rule (a Formatting Rule in this case) to do the trick. You have actions to "Hide this control" or "Disable this control" and you can base those actions on conditions (e.g. who is currently logged in).

Comment: I need to set read only properties to the field to particular group of user,And it should be visible for other user group. how to do this

Comment: The method that I mention works for groups as well as users. Were you able to find the settings that I mentioned? Are you using InfoPath 2010 or 2007?

Comment: no i didn't find..i am using info path 2010

Comment: On the "Data" ribbon, click on "Show Fields". Then right click on the field you want to format (disable) and take the option to add a rule.  Here is an interesting post on this topic that may give you other things to consider as well: http://www.infopathdev.com/forums/p/12516/44027.aspx.